# Codeigniter custom libraries vs core classes

Tags: codeigniter, class

i am new in codeigniter, i have read about custom libraries and core classes are commonly used in codeigniter but i am confused what is the difference b/w Custom libraries and core classes and where to use library (custom) or core class. Thank in advance.

Comment: Core class is part of Codeigniter (or the package you download) and custom library is a third party library you can add to run on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

1.**Libraries**: The libraries folder contains standard CodeIgniter
    libraries (to help you with e-mail, calendars, file uploads, and
    more). You can create your own libraries or extend (and even
    replace) standard ones, but those will be saved in the
    application/libraries directory to keep them separate from the
    standard CodeIgniter libraries saved in this particular folder.

2.**Core Classes**: This folder contains CodeIgniter’s core class. Do not modify anything here. All of your work will take place in the application folder. Even if your intent is to extend the CodeIgniter core, you have to do it with hooks, and hooks live in the application folder.

Another different is: In libraries you have to create CI instance for using CI system files.But not need to create in core class.For example if you need to load url helper in libraries.Then the way is

```
$this->CI = &get instance();//creates a CI instance
$this->CI->load->helper('url');//loads database
```

But in core class you have not need to create instance.So helper can load directly as

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: Thanx, but where to use libraries and where to use core classse ?

Comment: If you wants to user certain function repeatedly in different modules than make a library with this function and and load library and call to  functions.

Comment: But core class make easy if you want to make your own controller(public,admin,private).Which extends your core system classes..such as CI_Controller,CI_Model